# How to get continuos line numbers for minted code blocks

Tags: formatting, minted, code, line-numbering, fancyvrb

I use `minted` in following way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

% Syntax higlight
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vim}
\newminted{bash}{bgcolor=Beige, fontfamily=tt,
  gobble=2, linenos, numbersep=-3pt}
\newmint{bash}{}
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{
  \sffamily
  \textcolor{BlueViolet}{
    \scriptsize
    \oldstylenums{
      \arabic{FancyVerbLine}
      }
    }
  }

\begin{document}

AAAA

\begin{bashcode}
  BBBB
  CCCC  
\end{bashcode}

DDDD

\begin{bashcode}
  EEEE
  FFFF 
\end{bashcode}

GGGG
\end{document}
```

With this settings I have separate line number for each code block, i.e.

```
1 AAAA
2 BBBB
```

and later

```
1 EEEE
2 FFFF
```

I'd like to get continuous all the time increasing line numbers, i.e.

```
1 AAAA
2 BBBB
```

and later

```
3 EEEE
4 FFFF
```

According to `fancyvrb` documentation I tried to add option `firstnumber=last` to `\newminted` definition, but it produces totally weird numbers, e.g. first code block starts with 16 and ends with 32, next starts with 43...

Comment: `firstnumber=last` doesn't distinguish between different `Verbatim` based environments.

Comment: I do not have any other `Verbatim` based environments. Well, I think. Only `enumerate`, `captions` and `table`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are using `minted` 1.7 or earlier.  Version 2.0 and later includes patches for some `fancyvrb` bugs. This should make `firstnumber=last` work correctly. (At least, it works for me.)  Also, since 2.0 there is a package option `langlinenos` that does per-language line numbering when `firstnumber=last`, so that you can keep `bash` line numbers separate from any other code.

If this doesn't work for you with `minted` 2.0+, then there is probably a bug in `minted`.

Comment: Indeed, in openSUSE repository there is outdated `minted` package. The newest works fine with the setting. I have requested its update i repository.

Comment: If I only use `bashcode` environments, there's no problem. But any `Verbatim` in between will spoil the numbering, for obvious reasons. You may consider a new option for `newminted`, say `firstnumber=*` which would set up a new counter like in my answer and pass `firstnumber=\value{<thisnewcounter>}` to `fancyvrb`.

Comment: @egreg The package option `langlinenos` creates a per-language counter. This is passed to `fancyvrb` as necessary, and then the original `fancyvrb` counter value is restored afterward, so that non-`minted` use of `fancyvrb` isn't affected. I suppose I could also consider an option to add a counter strictly restricted to a given custom command.

Answer (score 5):

The `firstnumber=last` option doesn't distinguish between different environments based on `Verbatim` (like `bashcode`). Thus, if you have other `minted` environments between two `bashcode` ones, the numbering will be somewhat unpredictable.

You can set a specific `bashnumber` counter that's stepped along with `bashcode` lines and set `\firstnumber=\value{bashnumber}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% fonts
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}

% Syntax higlight

\usemintedstyle{vim}
\newminted{bash}{bgcolor=Beige, fontfamily=tt,
  gobble=2, linenos, numbersep=6pt,firstnumber=\value{bashnumber}}
\newmint{bash}{}
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{%
  \sffamily
  \textcolor{BlueViolet}{%
    \scriptsize
    \oldstylenums{%
      \stepcounter{bashnumber}%
      \arabic{FancyVerbLine}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcounter{bashnumber}
\setcounter{bashnumber}{1}

\begin{document}

AAAA

\begin{bashcode}
  BBBB
  CCCC  
\end{bashcode}

DDDD

\begin{minted}{c}
abc
\end{minted}

XXXXX

\begin{bashcode}
  EEEE
  FFFF 
\end{bashcode}

GGGG
\end{document}
```

Note the proper formatting of the redefinition of `\theFancyVerbLine` so the `numbersep` option can have a decent value.

[image]

Comment: This is perfectly working, but I consider it as a workaround as it works as expected with newest version of `minted` package. For some reason there is outdated version in openSUSE repository...